# how add or display column value which come from other table calculation in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

```
leave_type_id        name        day
    1          Sick Leave        12  
    3           Maternity        84     
    4         asual Leave        12  
   41      Marriage Leave         5  
   42      Optional Leave         2  




Leave_applied_Id   employee_id leave_type_id  status
'1'                '66'         '46'          '3'
'2'                '28'         '1'           '5'
'3'                '897'        '1'           '5'
'4'                '854'        '4'           '2'




SELECT 
count(employee_id)  
FROM Parabola.leave_applied 
where leave_type_id=4 and employee_id=854 and status=2;
```

This Query we get Count so i want display like :

```
leave_type_id           name    applied
4             Casual Leave       1/12
1               Sick Leave       0/12
3                Maternity       0/84
41          Marriage Leave        0/5
42          Optional Leave        0/2
```

please help me how i will create trigger or any other thing

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please add your expected output based on given data.

Comment: expected output : LEAVEID, NAME, day/calculated count which is coming from my given Query @1000111

Comment: Actually I asked for data not only the format of your output. Please add your expected output in the question not int the comment.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/m8LKrD85KCtemRjXT2CVzQ  this i want @1000111

Comment: I understand that the second table holds all the applied leaves. But what's the `status`  field?

Comment: status filed two means his leave was approved that count is ok i just want to display that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
 leavetable.leave_type_id,
 leavetable.`name`,
 CONCAT(COALESCE(t.totalAppliedLeave,'0'),'/',leavetable.`day`) AS applied
FROM leavetable
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        leave_type_id,
        employee_id,
        COUNT(*) totalAppliedLeave
    FROM leave_applied
    WHERE employee_id=854 AND `status` = 2
    GROUP BY employee_id,leave_type_id
) AS t
ON leavetable.leave_type_id = t.leave_type_id;
```

**Output:**

Running the above query on your given data you will get the following output for `employee_id = 854`

```
leave_type_id           name    applied
4             Casual Leave       1/12
1               Sick Leave       0/12
3                Maternity       0/84
41          Marriage Leave        0/5
42          Optional Leave        0/2
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31282/2/0)

Comment: OK let me do i will  tell you Once i will face Prob

Comment: Please check the fiddle first. And you need to change the table name which I used as `leaveTable`

Comment: Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'Parabola.leave_applied.leave_type_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
  @1000111 51 this error coming

Comment: Please check now @ResearchDevelopment

Comment: again thank you @1000111 i am wrting first time Query an all so for this thanx

Comment: You are welcome dear! I am happy to hear that it worked for you. Happy Coding!

Comment: @ 1000111 5 if you dont mind can you teach me some MySql related this because i am beginner  sudden i got work in this please

Comment: I would suggest you to go through a good tutorial (sequentially) and whenever you get stuck search for similar problems. Nevertheless, if your issue isn't solved then ask here (**Stack Overflow**). That's the purpose of  this site. Just in case if you need elaborate explanation regarding any of your posts on `MySQL` just let me know. I'll try my best to help.

Comment: Ok Thnkyou very much how i will Ping You if I need Ur help ?

Comment: You can use this comment section just like you did it a moment ago. :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117271/discussion-between-1000111-and-research-development).

Comment: In same thing we have to in place applied name will change as label and Vale will come  status+name+day please help @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1714187/1000111